# Array to String from a db query - Very Specific issue

Tags: php

I need help converting an array to sting -> i only need the value from the database.

inserting into DB

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tickets1 (lastName, firstName, Address, policyNo, IdNumber, Test, Medicals)
VALUES ('$last', '$first', '$Address', '$policyNo', '$IdNumber', '$Tests', '$medical');";


mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```

Pulling data i put into db table

```
 $result = $connect->query("SELECT TicketID FROM tickets1 where IdNumber = '$IdNumber'");
```

creating an array with the data

```
$meds = array();
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $meds[] = $rows;
}
$meds1 = print_r($meds, true); // <- convert to an array
```

I have tried `json_encode()`, `var_dump`, `implode` but it does not give me the value in the database.

Instead it gives me :

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(1) { 
        ["TicketID"]=> string(2) "72" 
    } 
} 
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [bloodID] => 1 
    ) 
)
```

Any ideas

Comment: Are you trying to create an object or  a string?

Comment: Where does `bloodID` come from? There's nothing like that in your code.

Comment: Do you expect $result to ever have more than one row? Do you expect $meds to ever have more than one row? Which array are you wanting to be as a string?

Comment: The bloodID comes from the DB

Comment: @FrancescoManicardi i am trying to pull the ID from the db table and place that into another table into the db based on a condition

Comment: @IncredibleHat yes at the most 10 rows

Comment: @Dharman i am aware of it and will use prepared statements for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just push the column you want into the array, not the whole row:

```
$meds[] = $rows['TicketID'];
```